# Django Class Based Listview with two filtered individual lists

Tags: django, class, django-queryset

Hi I am trying to create a page that uses model **Item** that has a model field called **data_type** with an integer choice selection of either 1 or 2. I currently have a Listview page and I am trying to create two lists, one that shows Items with data_type=1 and the other that shows data_type=2.

1 represents models and 2 represents scripts, if that helps?

Here is my views.py

```
class ItemListView(generic.ListView):


    context_object_name = 'model_list'
    queryset = Item.objects.filter(data_type='1')

    context_object_name = 'script_list'
    queryset = Item.objects.filter(data_type='2')

    template_name = 'item_list.html',
```

Item_list.html

```
<h3 class="text-muted text-center mt-4">Models</h3>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-4">
  {% if model_list %}
    {% for item in model_list %}
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card card-primary card-effects p-2 mb-3 mt-4">
      <a href="{% url 'portal:item_detail' item.pk %}" class="card-full-link">
      <img class="card-img" src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="225" height="185">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="text-muted"> {{ item.get_data_type_display }}</p>
        <h4 class="text-left"> {{ item.name }}<span class="text-blue">Ξ{{ item.price }}</span></h4>
      </div>
      </a>
      <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p> !-->
    </div>
  </div>
          {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <p>There are no items in the database.</p>
    {% endif %}


  </div>
</div>

<h3 class="text-muted text-center mt-4">Scripts </h3>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-4">
  {% if script_list %}
    {% for item in script_list %}
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card card-primary card-effects p-2 mb-3 mt-4">
      <a href="{% url 'portal:item_detail' item.pk %}" class="card-full-link">
      <img class="card-img" src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="225" height="185">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="text-muted"> {{ item.get_data_type_display }}</p>
        <h4 class="text-center"> {{ item.name }}<span class="text-blue">Ξ{{ item.price }}</span></h4>
      </div>
      </a>
      <!-- <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p> !-->
    </div>
  </div>
          {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
      <p>There are no items in the database.</p>
    {% endif %}


  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully the views.py will give you an idea what I am trying to do. It seems that I can't have two context_object_name and querysets. If I remove the vottom context_object_name and queryset, the model_list will load.

I got the context_object_name queryset idea from django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `get_context_data` method:

```
class ItemListView(generic.ListView):

    context_object_name = 'model_list'
    queryset = Item.objects.filter(data_type='1')

    template_name = 'item_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ItemListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['script_list'] = Item.objects.filter(data_type='2')
        return context
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. That makes sense, not sure why I didn't think to use get_context_data!